# open chrome browser in vb "web browser control"

Tags: google-chrome, vb6, webbrowser-control

I am new to vb 6.0.

I have to open any browser other than Internet Explorer in the web browser control of vb (which open IE by default)

I have tried many codes and I can now open browser as if it is new window (by using process.start etc)

Is there any way to open it in existing vb control?

Comment: VB.Net 6.0  that it self Wrong. either Visual Basic 6.0 or Visual Basic.NEt (.Net 2.0, 3.0,3.5, 4.0, 4.5).  You can use WebBrowser Control is availlble in Visual Studio. Do you want to Open Chorme / Safari  if that you can open chorme by Proces.Start . the question is not proper to give answer.

Comment: yes it is Visual Basic 6.0 , I can open IE with web browser control and I want it to be mozilla or any webkit browser instead, Is it possible to do?

Comment: You can use Mozilla FirFox also

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10971216/17776

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by using a webbrowser control other than IE that you cannot accomplish with it?

Comment: I am working on html5 and we have to execute some code to preview our end html o/p which will obviously be in a browser . I am supposed to show it embedded in a form or a vb control. But unfortunately IE does not support many of the HTML5 features I want mozilla / chrome / opera / safari (preferably mozilla / chrome).

Answer (score 2):

The web browser control IS Internet Explorer. So unless chrome et al release a ActiveX control of their browser, which they haven't, it is not possible.

There is a workaround is that you start chrome and then hook it's CreateWindowsEx and put your Apps Window as the owner. Then size it where you would have the web browser control using `SetWindowPos`. This gives the following features

- An owned window is always above its owner in the Z order.
- The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is destroyed.
- An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

  sAppName = "Google Chorme"
  sAppPath = "C:\Users\082043\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"


    Shell sAppPath, vbMinimizedFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. OP has stated he/she wants to open chrome in existing vb control.

Comment: First read his comment. in that he specifically put the requrement. from

Comment: "I have tried many codes and I can now open browser as if it is new window (by using process.start etc)". For all intents and purposes, `Shell` falls under the same umbrella as `<System.Diagnostics>.Process.Start` which, interestingly, is part of .NET, not VB6... Back to your point, you have provided an option which OP has already implemented, as stated in his question. He asked for a webkit browser in said comment. @jac jas answered the question (which has been answered many times, see his link).

Comment: thr Requrement here in Vb 6.0 not .Net. System.Daigsnostics .Net

Comment: it is .net 6.0 by mistake  I wrote VB 6.0

Comment: There is not .Net 6.0, and .Net 1.0,2,3,3.5,4 , 4.5.. I dont know about .Net 6.0

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code to invoke the default browser (applies to VB 6).

Place this at very top, but below the 'Option' declarations.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
```

Place this where 'Sub' are placed' This invokes the default browser to go to google.com.

```
Private Sub cmdBUTTON_Click()

ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, "http://www.google.com", vbNullString, vbNullString, 10

End Sub
```

You could find information on the variables [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) .