# Reading Web Pages with Visual Basic 6

Tags: html, vb6

I want to create a Web Browser with Visual Basic 6. The only possible way I found to create this is using 'Microsoft Internet Controls' ActiveX plugin (WebBrowser). But, it is using Internet Explorer to show pages. I don't like it. I want to show the Web Pages in a modern, well designed way. So, I am going to create a program which can read and display HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP etc. Is it possible to do that with only using Visual Basic 6?

MS Internet Controls I am currently using:

[image]

Comment: The browser control does use the IE that's installed on your system, so probably IE 11?  But it runs in document mode 7, so it's essentially emulating IE 7, that's why it wouldn't look 'modern' to you. There are workarounds for this, either a registry change or a meta tag in the html, that instructs IE to run in the latest document mode.  See https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version for an explanation. If you were to use .Net you could use webview with Edge, or DotNetBrowser with Chromium, but those aren't available for VB6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open chrome browser in vb "web browser control"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200807/open-chrome-browser-in-vb-web-browser-control)

Comment: @DaveInCaz … which unfortunately has not a single useful answer.

Comment: Short answer: it’s possible but probably quite a lot of work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph granted... but that's not the criteria for being a duplicate AFAIK. There's not much point in having two of them. If this one already had good answers I would have suggested the dupe go the other way.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Agreed, this wasn’t meant as a criticism.

Comment: @KonradRudolph understood, no worries! :)